# How to pass through a PHP object from one page to the next twice?

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

```
$ID= $_GET['id'];

<form method="post" action="updateorder.php?id=?"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ID);?>">
```

I am using PHP and I can pass through the ID from the index.php to this page (openorders).  I would like to go from this (openorders.php) to another page to update my orders - updateorder.php.  I have found how to pass it through once, but not one more time after that.  How would you do this?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.session.php)?

Comment: you can do it without sessions, but as @HenriqueBarcelos suggested, it would be less a hassle if you did use sessions. should have used the English link though http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php ;-)

Comment: Thank's, @Fred-ii-. I think php.net geotag is throwing me by default to the Portuguese version of the site, I didn't pay attention.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos No worries and you're welcome ;-)

Comment: I only needed it for one extra form.. that's why I wasn't thinking of sessions.  I will be using sessions for the login to get here later

Comment: @SDJ I posted an answer earlier with an example. However, I noticed something about your syntax in your form and I have made an edit to that effect and can be found under **Edit** under my original answer. I'm not sure if you saw it or not. It's about `?id=?"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, use sessions and as an example.

**Sidenote:** Consult my **"Edit"** further below about `?id=?"` in your form.

- Assign a session array to the GET array, then use the same session array for subsequent pages.

The variable names don't really matter, it's the session array that is important here.

First start with, and from the page where you will retrieve the GET array:

```
session_start();

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
   $ID = $_GET['id'];
}

$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];

$var_page1 = $_SESSION['id'];
   echo "ID #: " . $var_page1;
```

then on the next page:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

   $var_page2 = $_SESSION['id'];
   echo "ID #: " . $var_page2;

}
```

and the subsequent page following that:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

   $var_page3 = $_SESSION['id'];
   echo "ID #: " . $var_page3;

}
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

---

Sidenote: If your GET array will always be an integer, you can pass `(int)` to it for more protection.

```
$ID = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

---

**Edit:** (something I noticed while testing) - I used `123` as an example, being:

```
$_GET['id'] = 123;
$ID = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Your form will need to be adjusted because of `?id=?"`. (the extra `?` and quote).

```
<form method="post" action="updateorder.php?id=?"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ID);?>">
                                               ^^ extra question mark and quote - delete it
```

Because that will translate to the following (and in HTML source) which is a `?` and adding an additional quote, which is something you don't want and will fail you.

```
<form method="post" action="updateorder.php?id=?"123">
```

It will need to be changed to the following:

```
<form method="post" action="updateorder.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ID);?>">
```

which will produce the following in HTML source:

```
<form method="post" action="updateorder.php?id=123">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get id value inside updateorder.php with this code. 
it is just because you are sending data with post in openorders.php. 
that why you can not get data with $_GET global

```
if(!empty($_POST['id'])){
$id = $_POST['id'];
}else{
$id=0;
}
```

Comment: Please leave and explanation with your code for OP to understand how your answer will help

Comment: That is false. You can use POST and GET together. The GET array is caught in the PHP (in the next page).

Comment: @Fred-ii- i did not say you can not get $_GET value. read carefully. he is trying to read post with get method